# LastModifiedProductVersion Property in SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to manage an SSIS Project.

In the Solution Explorer, I

1. Select the solution node and right mouse click and select "Properties
2. Click Configuration Properties/General
3. Select a Target Server Version of "SQL Server 2012" to  match the target SQL Server

If I open up one of the packages in the solution with Notepad, it shows

```
DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="11.0.7462.6"
```

Which, I believe, indicates a SQL Server 2012 level package.

However, if I make any changes to the package from within this solution, the packages is updated and this line is modified to

```
DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.1100.123"
```

A version of 15 suggests SQL 2019.

Furthermore, I am really troubled by the fact that a Production package that successfully imports a file dies when running on my computer when it tried to import NULL values. I seem to have to set the "Retain Null Values" property on the Data Source to get it to work on mine. What is really bizarre is that when it runs in Production, it changes NULL date values to non-null values and I do not see any transformations, SQL, triggers or default values that can account for the imported date values getting non-null values in prod.

On my machine, again, it dies when null values are encountered, hence I am investigating package version difference and question why this SQL version property is being updated to reflect 2019 even though I try to target 2012.

My one explicit question is: does this suggest that my package is not saved as a SQL Server 2012 version package?

```
DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.1100.123"
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain @ChadD! A couple of years ago, I made the mistake of upgrading my visual studio from the 2012 BIDS to Visual Studio 2015 for SQL Server 2012. It caused all types of odd behavior with SSIS and SSAS, not to mention any SSRS report I opened would fail when re-deployed to our server. I even tried editing the XML of files directly to correct, but that was an exercise in futility.

What worked best for us, and I would suggest for you is to **create a VM with just the 2012 edition tools**. This makes it SO much easier to switch between legacy projects and new projects. I've always been one to want to try the latest and greatest tools, but it's just not worth it in this case. Having a dedicated VM environment for the targeted edition is my route going forward!

Comment: It's always confused me how to get the proper version of BIDS, SSDT, and or visual Studio to match the target SQL Server database version. I was told that Only VS 2017 and above are now available. I have an ISO for SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition. Will that give me what I need to manage SSIS 2012 packages? THis is a mess

Comment: @ChadD, Yes! In the setup wizard under the "Feature Selection" > "Shared Features", select "SQL Server Data Tools"